# Xamarin Xaml Bind height of button to height of Label

Tags: xaml, xamarin, button, label

I got a label and a button next to each other in a grid. I'm trying to get the button to match its Height with the Label.

current XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- vessel label and button -->
    <Label StyleClass="headerSub" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="currentVesselLabel" 
           Text="huidig voertuig:"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="selecteer voertuig" 
            BindingContext="{x:Reference currentVesselLabel}"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Path=HeightRequest}"
            ClassId="selectVesselButton" x:Name="selectVesselButton"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried setting the `BindingContext` to the label and bind the `HeightRequest` property of the button to the Label's `Height` and `HeightRequest` property. However, both don't work. How do I bind the height of the button to the height of the Label?

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't touched my pc in a few days. Your solution works for the time being, but  I would rather have it  bind to the height of the label, without setting a HeightRequest on the label itself (check my other comment). Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

It seems that you forgot to set the height of row.When there is only one row in the grid.The default height of row will be set as the height of screen.

**Solution:**

Set the height of the row.Refer to the following code:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- vessel label and button -->
    <Label StyleClass="headerSub" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="currentVesselLabel" 
       Text="huidig voertuig:" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="60"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="selecteer voertuig" 
        BindingContext="{x:Reference currentVesselLabel}"
        HeightRequest="{Binding Path=HeightRequest}"
        ClassId="selectVesselButton" x:Name="selectVesselButton"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hey there! Sorry for the late response. The code shown above was part of a larger picture, so the height of the grid row wasn't the issue. The way I bound the height was binding to the `HeightRequest` of the label, which was not set at the time. Setting this property (as you did) binds the heightrequest of the button to the heightRequest of the label. However, for the sake of the question, do you know how to achieve this without setting a HeightRequest of the label?

Comment: Where did you set the height of label? Can you provide a sample ?

Comment: I´m using the `small` font size, otherwise I've not set a custom height. All HeaderSub is `.headerSub { 
    font-size: small; 
    color: #BBBBBB; 
    margin: 5, 0, 0, 0; 
}` in a CSS file.